# Why Rails is often quoted with Cloud computing and software as a service?

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, azure, cloud, saas

I have recently started learning about Software as a Service and Cloud computing. Often I see people mentioning Rails framework while talking about SAAS and cloud computing and I was wondering why?

Is there anything special related to cloud computing & SAAS in Rails' framework & tooling as compared to others for example Microsoft's .Net and Azure? Or have I misunderstood and it is just the coincidence that I heard about Rails and SAAS/Cloud computing together?

Comment: While Rails is used to develop SAAS platforms so are many other languages. The articles that you read may mention Rails for a number of different reasons depending on the context and intended audience. Finding the two topics mentioned together may be a product of the two. This question is hard to answer because there are no definitive answers that can be backed up with sources or facts. Any chance on rewording the question?

Comment: I don't think question needs a re-write. You and others understood my point. I guess a stupid question :)

Comment: Good to hear you got what you were looking for, it's not that the question was stupid just that it was hard to answer without resorting to anecdotal evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ git push heroku master

The deployment approach using Heroku (PaaS) and Github (SaaS) had (still has) a huge impact on how web applications are built and deployed. The automatic acceptance of that mechanism by the Ruby community means that deploying to the cloud is second nature and part of the rails DNA. Package management (gems), and again their automatic support, also helped.

Answer (score 0):

There's really not anything special about Rails that makes it "extra cloudy".

Probably, except for the fact that Rails instances are independent of each other ([shared-nothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture)), and you can spin as many workers as you want. But many technologies have this quality.